# Cannot open file from external storage (getting various errors)

Tags: android, kotlin, storage, android-permissions

I'm trying to make an app that would process some data (ideally) from a file in a random folder. For now I struggle to use a file with a hardcoded path:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var fileDir = ""
    var data = mutableListOf<List<String>>()
    val toAddPermissions = mutableListOf<String>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fetch_button)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "*/*"

        toAddPermissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        toAddPermissions.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            if(hasReadPermission() && hasWritePermission())
                fetch()
        }

        requestPermission()
    }

    private fun requestPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, toAddPermissions.toTypedArray(), 0)
    }

    private fun hasReadPermission() =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun hasWritePermission() =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun fetch(){
        val file = File(*some string*)
        val bufferedReader = file.bufferedReader()
        //some code processing contents of the file
    }
```

where depending on *some string* i get these errors:
getExternalFilesDir("/storage/emulated/0/Download/sample3.txt").toString() ->  open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
"/storage/emulated/0/Download/sample3.txt" -> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.matto.telemetry">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Telemetry">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I went through various posts both in Kotlin and Java with no results. Do you have any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: `For now I struggle to use a file with a hardcoded path:` ???? Where are you talking about? I see ACTION_GET_CONTENT so you let the user select a file and you will get an uri.

Comment: You do not have read access to files in the downloads directory, except for files that your app installation wrote there. Use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`) and let the user choose the document to open. You will find this covered in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) and [this free book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore).